Why does an emitted event with "good ordering" consume more gas in Solidity, and how does argument order affect gas costs?
I conducted a test in Solidity using Remix to understand how the order of arguments affects gas consumption in events and function calls. Specifically, I tested the following code:
event Test1Event(
    uint256 _1,
    string _5,
    uint256 _2,
    address _4,
    bool _6,
    address _3,
    bool _7,
    string _8
);

event Test2Event(
    uint256 _1,
    uint256 _2,
    address _3,
    address _4,
    bool _5,
    bool _6,
    string _7,
    string _8
);

function test1(
    uint256 _1,
    uint256 _2,
    address _3,
    address _4,
    bool _5,
    bool _6,
    string calldata _7,
    string calldata _8
) external {
    emit Test1Event(_1, _7, _2, _4, _6, _3, _5, _8);
}

function test2(
    uint256 _1,
    uint256 _2,
    address _3,
    address _4,
    bool _5,
    bool _6,
    string calldata _7,
    string calldata _8
) external {
    emit Test2Event(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8);
}

Observations:
The event Test1Event has a seemingly "bad order" in terms of data alignment for gas efficiency, yet consumes less gas than Test2Event.
The function test1 and test2 have the same parameter list but emit events with different field orderings.
I noticed the gas cost of emitting the event and the function call are both affected, which is counterintuitive because I expected "good ordering" to reduce gas costs.
Questions:
Why does the "good order" of fields in Test2Event consume more gas than the "bad order" in Test1Event?
How does the order of function arguments impact gas costs, and is it different from how event field ordering affects gas consumption?
What is the best practice for ordering fields in events and arguments in functions to minimize gas costs?

While testing this, I've observed another interesting thing when I interchanged the names of the events, the gas consumption is getting interchanged too. I've created this gist containing two contracts OriginalTest (having the same body as you've shared) and Test (having interchanged event names). They're having the comments regarding the corresponding gas consumptions. Also, I'm using compiler version 0.8.24, EVM version Paris, and testing on Remix VM (Paris). Can you cross-check the same on your end?

@SYEDASADKAZMI  yeah on my end it behaves like you mentioned.And this behavior is very strange,as I cant do correctly decrease gas cost

I think this gas diff is from contract dispatcher.
function selector for your "function test1" is "821DB9E5" and  function selector for your "function test1" is "CC7B754E".
If you get a assembly code of your contract, In dispatcher firstly compare calldata with "821DB9E5" and if false then compare with "CC7B754E".
so for calling "test2" function dispatcher exec more opcodes.
If you swap function names you'll see the order of argument has no effect.
This is part of your contract dispacther :
PUSH 0
CALLDATALOAD
PUSH E0
SHR
DUP1
PUSH 821DB9E5 ==> selector function "test1"
EQ
PUSH [tag] 3
JUMPI
DUP1
PUSH CC7B754E ==> selector function "test2"
EQ
PUSH [tag] 4
JUMPI

Based on my testing of the ordering behavior of static and dynamic fields in events, it’s not behaving as expected.
To ensure a guaranteed reduction in the gas cost of event emissions, you can avoid using dynamic types like string in your event. Instead, replace them with their hashes of type bytes32, for example:
event OptimizedEvent(
    uint256 _1,
    uint256 _2,
    address _3,
    address _4,
    bool _5,
    bool _6,
    bytes32 _7,
    bytes32 _8
);

And, you can emit the same in your function, like:
function test3(
    uint256 _1,
    uint256 _2,
    address _3,
    address _4,
    bool _5,
    bool _6,
    string calldata _7,
    string calldata _8
) external {
    emit OptimizedEvent(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_7)), keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_8)));
}

So, by hashing dynamic data, you can achieve better gas optimization while still retaining the ability to verify the data off-chain.
You can also refer to this answer to understand how the event gas cost is calculated. Since the calculation uses the number of the unindexed bits, avoiding dynamic types with larger data while emitting the event can significantly reduce the gas cost.
